# Autocompute using ajax values provided in the database onchange

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html-select

I have no idea how to basically use this. Im thinking of using javascipt arrays though.

Well I have a select option here with values from the database and the select is dynamic. The "add row" button will add another row of option select:

```
<td>Items </td>
<td style="text-align:left;">
   <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
   <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

   <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" >
      <TR>
         <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
         <TD>
            <select name="ItemNo[]" id="select" value="ItemNo" onChange="this.disabled=true;">  

            <?php 
               $sql2="select * from jewelry_system.item where NumStored !='0' order by ItemName asc"; 
               $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
               while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            ?>

             <option value="<?php echo $row2['ItemNo']?>"> 
                <?php echo $row2['ItemName'];?>     
                Php:<?php echo $row2['SalePrice'];?> </option>
             <?php } ?>

             </select>
          </TD>
       </TR>
    </TABLE>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is what should be changed by ajax?

```
<tr>
   <td>Total Payment (Php):</td>
   <td> <div id="tpayment">0.00</div> </td>
</tr>
```

I wanted to compute total payment onChange of the values in the select option. and since the value can only be changed once should i use arrays? I'm quite clueless to ajax, tried learning at w3schools but failed.

pls thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might not need AJAX unless you are needing to set something in your database prior to clicking a "submit" button of some sort.  It looks like you should be able to store all the information in your selects when you build your page with PHP.  You would need to show/hide your selects in the document using javascript.

Add **;updateTotal()** to your select onChange event:

```
<select name="ItemNo[]" id="select1" value="ItemNo" onChange="this.disabled=true;updateTotal()">
```

Then add this function to your page or your javascript file:

```
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function updateTotal() {
            var dropdown = document.getElementById('select1');
            var total = 0;
            for (var i=0; i<dropdown.length; i++){
                if (dropdown.options[i].selected) {
                    total += dropdown.options[i].value;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('tpayment').innerHTML = total;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Since you're going to be adding/removing rows, you will need to keep track of them like you mentioned with an array - probably a global one.

at the beginning of your javascript, declare a global array to store your datatables like this:

```
var selects = new Array();
```

You'll also want to update your add/remove calls:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable','select1')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable','select1')" />
```

Then, when you call your addRow function, do this:

```
function addRow(rowname,selectname) {
    /* ... original function stuff ... */
    selects.push(selectname); /* this will add the selectname to the selects array */
}
```

And likewise, when you call your removeRow function, do this:

```
function removeRow(rowname,selectname) {
    /* ... original function stuff ... */
    selects.splice(selects.indexOf(selectname),1);
    updateTotal(); /* since selected items might have been removed */
}
```

And lastly, we'll modify our original function like this:

```
function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var h=0; h<selects.length; h++) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById(selects[h]);
        for (var i=0; i<dropdown.length; i++){
            if (dropdown.options[i].selected) {
                total += dropdown.options[i].value;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('tpayment').innerHTML = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: both getElementById and innerHTML are case sensitive so make sure those are correct (I fixed it where I had innerHtml instead).

Comment: Also, you'll want to make sure that each of your <select> elements has a unique ID, such as select1, select2 etc.